# Ip address overlaps fa0/0

Tags: cisco

I'm having hard time, I assigned ip 192.168.9.0 to fa0/0 and tried to assign 192.168.9.32 to fa0/1. In the subsequent, I get the error 192.168.9.32 overlaps fastethernet0/0

Comment: What are netmasks (both)? And what do you want to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, it's hard to tell exactly what you did wrong, but it appears you have tried to configure two interfaces in the same subnet.  Each router interface must be in a separate subnet.

If, for example, you configured fa 0/0 with 192.168.9.0 and a mask of 255.255.255.0, then 192.168.9.32 falls within that subnet, and the router will reject it.

Comment: This could easily be correct if they have different netmasks (in case of proxy-arp), or both have /32 netmasks (no networks to overlap), or if those interfaces are put into different VRF. Also it is wrong to configure 192.168.9.0 with mask 255.255.255.0, but it would be correct if mask was set to 255.255.254.0.